# Flutter - Unhandled Exception: SocketException:

Tags: flutter

I am facing below error while accessing the web services in android app. But its working fine in iOS app.Pl help us to resolve this issue

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = localhost, port = 47992

Comment: Do you have the Internet permission in the Manifest?

Comment: can you post flutter doctor log over here?
And also some code snippet if possible.

Comment: [try this it may resolve...] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57241086/10434475)

Answer (score -1):

Also I have faced the same problem. 
The way I have solved my problem is,

I made sure that there is no error in my code. Then I uninstalled my app, after that I restarted my phone and install the app again. Then it start working.

I hope this will help..

Comment: This doesn't work as I understood that the OP wants this in Android Emulator, not on a real device